# How to Simulate Touch and Hold in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

Anyone knows?

Touch and hold...

Should we like set a timer at touch down event?

Comment: Could you please describe what you have tried, or the results of your research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using iOS 3.2 or later, just use [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). For prior versions, you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565889/iphone-how-to-get-functionality-of-long-press-gesture-in-ios-ver-below-3-2).